# Drupal Views Nivo Slider "undifined offset error"

Tags: php, jquery, drupal, drupal-views, nivo-slider

im trying to use the "views nivo slider" module after the minor update to the lates drupal i am always seeing this error

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in template_preprocess_views_nivo_slider_view_nivo_sliderfields() (line 122 of /var/www/html/drupal/modules/views_nivo_slider/views_nivo_slider.module).
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in template_preprocess_views_nivo_slider_view_nivo_sliderfields() (line 122 of /var/www/html/drupal/modules/views_nivo_slider/views_nivo_slider.module).
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in template_preprocess_views_nivo_slider_view_nivo_sliderfields() (line 122 of /var/www/html/drupal/modules/views_nivo_slider/views_nivo_slider.module).
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in template_preprocess_views_nivo_slider_view_nivo_sliderfields() (line 122 of /var/www/html/drupal/modules/views_nivo_slider/views_nivo_slider.module).
```

It seems the slider is trying to pull in new pages that i have created.

These are the effected lines from views_nivo_slider.module

```
  switch ($id) {
  case $options['image_field']:
  //$image_url = $field_output;
  $field_image_name = "field_{$options['image_field']}";
  $image_url = $field_output = $row->{$field_image_name}[0]['raw']['uri'];
  break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted the entire nivo slider install and associated data, and then re-installed.

Problem solved!! :S